# Why is 005, 05, and 5 same for excel vba even it is converted to text?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that would alert me(no mather how) if there is a double,tripple... input of INVOICE number(if I try to input an Invoice that has been already stored) in same column. As there are invoices number like 00202, or 0-505, and also 202 and 505, it alerts me like this is the same numbers for program.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim dataRange As Range, oneCell As Range

    Set dataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("b7:b15") 'short range for testing

    For Each oneCell In dataRange
        If 1 < Application.CountIf(dataRange, oneCell.Value) Then

            oneCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Double!"

        End If
    Next oneCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how COUNTIF works with numeric data (it will do the same in a cell). You could use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim dataRange As Range, oneCell As Range

    Set dataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("b7:b15")    'short range for testing

    For Each oneCell In dataRange
        ' if cell is empty or contains "" don't do anything
        If onecell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            ' evaluate simply evaluates the formula string passed to it.
            ' and SUMPRODUCT doesn't have the same number conversion issue as COUNTIF
            If 1 < ActiveSheet.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(" & dataRange.Address & "=" & oneCell.Address & "))") Then

                oneCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Double!"

            End If
        End If
    Next oneCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes: I wrote `oncell` instead of `onecell` - corrected now.

Comment: Oh yes finally it works. So it was syntax afterall?! Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can you translate from first IF what this code exactly do, for my future work? I'm not familiar with evaluate, and this "nullString".